# Spring Rest - file upload to support UTF-8 file names

Tags: spring, file-upload, utf-8, spring-rest

In I am using file upload with Spring rest and `MultipartFile`.
everything is fine, but issue on UTF-8. it is **NOT** supporting **international** file name - it is replacing characters to **"?"** like this.

I tried to use encoding Filter -`org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter` , but no Luck.

But surprised, same above filter working fine for JSP form, without Rest
like this

```
<form:form method="POST" action="uploadFile" enctype="multipart/form-data" accept-charset="UTF-8">
```

Please help,  how to support this utf-8 in Spring Rest.

Comment: Have you tried @RequestMapping(value = "/api/customer", produces = "text/plain;charset=UTF-8")

Comment: Yup I have tried this one also.no success :-(

Comment: Have you compared the HTTP request for the JSP from and your API call (For example Postman?). Are there any differences. Did you load Spring MVC to test this or an external site hosting the form?

Comment: Hi Garry, it is rest call, both client and host are in two different server.In monolithic application in jsp with filter it is working fine.

Comment: What you've done should work... Try making a Spring Boot with one RestController and see how this works. It might be a configuration conflict or library issue.

Answer (score 0):

There are three steps to support - file upload with international name in Rest.

1. Configure the server to support UTF

   in my case Jboss 6.1

   `<property name="org.apache.catalina.connector.URI_ENCODING" value="UTF-8"/>`
2. Use UTF-8 filter

   `org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter`
3. pass the file name as parameter, and in host read the file from parameter instead of `MultipartFile`